# Invoking the correct instance of an overloaded function template when passing derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overload-resolution

Let's say I have a class template

```
template <class Ta>
struct Base {};
```

And I've written some overloaded function templates around it:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>&, T2){
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>&, Base<T2>&){
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

When I invoke the functions:

```
    Base<float> base1;
    Base<float> base2;
    f(base1,1);
    f(base1,base2);
```

I get exactly what I'd expect:

```
1
2
```

All is well, but now I want to create a derived class:

```
template <class Ta, class Tb> 
struct Derived : Base<Ta> {};
```

All of a sudden, when I run the same code on instances of the derived class:

```
    Derived<float,int> derived1;
    Derived<float,int> derived2;
    f(derived1,1);
    f(derived1,derived2);
```

I get a different result:

```
1
1
```

Apparently, the compiler interprets `T2=Derived<Ta,Tb>`, and does not interpret the alternate overload as having greater specificity.

What is the best way to clarify to the compiler that calls to `f(derived1,derived2)` should be interpreted as calls to `f(Base<T1>, Base<T2>)`?

---

Full [minimal example](https://godbolt.org/z/dEhf19)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Ta>
struct Base {};

template <class Ta, class Tb> 
struct Derived : Base<Ta> {};


template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>&, T2){
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>&, Base<T2>&){
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Base<float> base1;
    Base<float> base2;
    f(base1,1);
    f(base1,base2);
    Derived<float,int> derived1;
    Derived<float,int> derived2;
    f(derived1,1);
    f(derived1,derived2);
}
```

Comment: FYI: [SO: C++ template function for derived class with std::is_base_of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42085326/7478597)

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to allow derived classes in a C++ template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30418542/7478597)

Comment: Notice that, as you take by value, you will have object slicing.

Comment: In my real world example, I'm passing by reference, but didn't notice I was doing that when I wrote the demo. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use SFINAE to restrict one overload:

As your `Base` is template, require custom traits (else [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) might be used):

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
std::true_type is_template_base_of_impl(const C<T>*);

template <template <typename> class C>
std::false_type is_template_base_of_impl(...);

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
using is_template_base_of = decltype(is_template_base_of_impl<C>(std::declval<const T*>()));
```

```
template <class T1, class T2, std::enable_if_t<!is_template_base_of<BaseClass, T2>::value, int> = 0>
void f(Base<T1>, T2){
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>, Base<T2>){
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c098c163f37cbd1c)

Comment: This seems promising. There's some parts I need to read up on, but I assume it's checking to see if T2 was implemented from the `Base` template?

Comment: BTW, the earlier edit to this post suggested maybe using `std::is_base_of_v`. I found out [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49f346fd8efb6a3c) I could just as well write a nontemplate parent class to `Base`, though this solution doesn't work if you lack control of `Base`. I'm going to document this in a separate post but will mark this one accepted.

Comment: @StPiere: `typename=std::enable_if_t<..>` can be hackjacked, and doesn't allow overloads with different conditions, `std::enable_if_t<.., int>=0` doesn't suffer from those defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Jarod42's answer got me looking into conditional compilation solutions and I found a valid solution using `std::is_base_of`. However, since `Base` is a template in this example, the solution requires creating a non-template parent class of `Base`:

```
struct Base2 {};

template <class Ta>
struct Base : Base2 {};
```

If this is done the rest of the solution is made a little easier:

```
template <class T1, class T2, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Base2, T2>::value, int> = 0>
void f(Base<T1>, T2){
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
void f(Base<T1>, Base<T2>){
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49f346fd8efb6a3c)

However this only works if you have control over `Base`, whereas I think Jarod42's answer works in the general case.